# How to iterate an table element after load using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is this first time that I'm using it for a project.

I was trying to retrieve a values inside table with class name `maintable`, however the result was always null, so I wrote the DOM inside file and looked for that className and I did not find, so I tried to waitFor this selector like this:

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const element = await page.waitForSelector('.maintable');
  const res = await element.evaluate((el) => el);
  await browser.close();
  return element;
```

the element return was well successful, I think, once I received several values, but in order to iterate children elements, `const res = await element.evaluate((el) => el);` that line returns `{}`.

```
  return page.waitForSelector('.maintable')
    .then((res) => {
      res.evaluate((el) => el);
      browser.close();
    });
```

That the returns is `undefined`

I'm reading a lot content but still confused for me, anyone can help to clarify this question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
  await page.waitFor('div[class=maintable]');

  await page.evaluate(() => {
          var tbls = document.getElementsByClassName("maintable");
          // Get first table rows
          var arr = tbls[0].rows; 
          // Get first row value 
          console.log(arr[0].innerText);
        });
```

See if you can get the first row value, then you can just iterate over it.

Comment: Nice, I would like of simplicity, but a question, inside `table.maintable tbody tr.roomName` 4 results and I would like to iterate with divs inside them, but Im stuck

Comment: Have u used map before? Something like: arr.map(el => { el.innerText } );

Answer (score 0):

The confusing thing about puppeteer is that your node.js variables aren't shared by puppeteer *(unless you pass them in as args to "evaluate")*. Consider pulling out the values etc. into the shape you want inside your evaluate callback - that way you can debug in browser devtools, something like:

```js
const tableSelector = '.maintable';
await page.waitForSelector(tableSelector);
// note async (so function returns a promise)
// and that the argument passed into the function was specified as the last argument to .evaluate
const res = await element.evaluate(async (selectorInBrowserContext) => {
  const table = document.querySelector(selectorInBrowserContext);
  // just assuming your first row is the header columns, and all cells are the same shape
  // this is probably a bad assumption!
  const [header, rows] = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  const keys = [...header.querySelectorAll('td,th')].map(el => el.textContent);
  const result = [...rows].map(row => {
    const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td,th');
    const obj = {};
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      obj[key] = cells[i].textContent;
    });
    return obj;
  });
  return result;
}, tableSelector);
console.log('my table result is!', res);
await browser.close();
```